# Is the android market app already installed on every Android phone

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I am developing an Android app, which will use **C2DM**. In order to use C2DM a **Gmail account must be logged in on the Android device**.

I searched and found that **if Android market app is installed then the Gmail account is always logged in** - therefore we don't need to create a separate Gmail account and log in to that account to use C2DM.

So is the Android market app installed on all devices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No Market must not be isntalled on all Apps but i think it is on more than 99% of all Phones. Some Custom ROMs like Cyanogen don't come with pre-installed Market.
But if Market is installed that does not mean that the user also has a (active) GMail account.

Comment: Thanks for reply. i have read somewhere that Each device has a default Gmail account associated with it. am i right or not

Comment: @WaseemKhan i think you're doing it wrong. [check this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html)

Comment: No that is wrong, a device must not have a gmail account. But if you distribute your app over android market you can be sure that alomost everyone has a google account.

Comment: i am not distributing it on Android market but i am creating it for some company and all employees of that company will be using this app. so i am not sure if all of them have gmail account or not. should i worry about Gmail account for each employee or not. should i assume that each member will have their Gmail account logged on Android ?

Comment: @Hardik i didn't mean that you are wrong, i meant that Waseem is wrong with his assumption that every devices has it's account.

Comment: @Waseem you can check if there is a google account using the AccountManager Class: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html